# MonogDB 3.4 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, mongodb-3.4

In the production application, we are using MongoDB 3.4 version.I have installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my local machine and tried to install Mongo 3.4 and bang my head against the wall. Please let me know your thoughts.  Here are my steps:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-enterprise/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise-3.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I just did this in a more "handmade way" perhaps...

Downloaded the application from here: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.24.tgz
(it is the, let's call vanila version from the mongodb page)

Uncompressed it on /opt:

`tar zxf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.24.tgz -C /opt/`

Symlink for shorter name:

`ln -s /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.24 /opt/mongo`

Created the user for mongo:

`useradd -r mongod`

then added the systemctl command:

```
echo "[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target" > /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

Reloaded systemctl:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

Then created the /etc/mongod.conf with the following content:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/mongo/database/
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:
#  replSetName: "mongodb-keys-replica-set"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

then start the service:

`systemctl start mongod`

Adjust the configurations and directory path as needed.

It works, is a somehow handmade solution for a legacy version for that ubuntu version. Won't update with apt-get or related... but just works as it should.

If in local, for testing purposes, maybe it's not a bad idea go with a docker image... but just a suggestion, not the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct however don't forget to:

1. create directories and files, change owner

   ```
   mkdir /opt/mongo/database
   touch /var/log/mongod.log

   chown mongod:mongod /var/log/mongod.log
   chown -R mongod:mongod /opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.24
   chown mongod:mongod /opt/mongo
   ```
2. execute as root this part, link to mongo was wrong and should be as below:

   ```
   echo "[Unit]
   Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=mongod
   ExecStart=/opt/mongo/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target" > /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way for this it seems because the official documentation itself says that for version 3.4, the only supported ubuntu versions are 16.04 and 14.04 (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

I tried following the above steps by ignivs but encountered this error everytime:

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.